# why there is no performance differences if I use where clause inside of inner join?

Tags: performance, google-bigquery, query-performance

Basically I have two different types of query in BQ. 
the first one:

```
select q2.name, q1.* , q2.val1 from table1 as q1
inner join 
(select name,val1, val2 from table2) as q2
on q1.name = q2.name
```

and second one is:

```
select q2.name, q1.* , q2.val1 from table1 as q1
inner join 
(select name,val1, val2 from table2  where val1 = "X") as q2
on q1.name = q2.name
```

so as you can see there, the only difference is filtering X value. When I filter the X value inside of table2, size of table2 is being almost half. So my expectation is seeing a reduction of bytes of data, when I apply the "where" clause. However when I run `--dry_run` in the BQ cli. I got exactly the same bytes of data.

```
Query successfully validated. Assuming the tables are not modified, running this query will process 6958332498714 bytes of data.
```

So can somebody explain why I got exactly the same processed data size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery reduces how much data is scanned in a couple scenarios:

- You have a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), and you [filter on the partitioning column](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables).
- You have a [clustered table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables), and you [filter on one of the columns used for clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables).

For other types of filters, however, such as if you don't partition or cluster a table, you will incur the cost of scanning the entire table. See the [query pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries) for more information.